# Why when an user change his password he cannot access his share folder

Tags: windows

I have a windows 7 network (workgroup) PCA and PCB
I have a share folder on PCA
I give user3 access to this folder (read)

Why when user3 change his password he cannot access the share folder
I just want to know why and how resolve this problem

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add punctuation marks.

Comment: Why don't you do it for him? He obviously isn't a native English speaker. :)

Comment: @Xavierjazz - Why not give somebody the chance to fix their mistakes?  If it still does not happen then you should do it.  Honestly that type of comment is frustrating.

Comment: Well, I'm sorry you find it frustrating, but I don't really agree. The OP can fix their mistakes (if they can) but many times I see questions that are obviously not by a native speaker. This isn't really a grammar site, and I think the question is more important.

Answer (score 3):

Since this is a workgroup, then the passwords for users are stored on each machine, and are specific to each individual machine.

If the user changes their password on one machine then one of two things has to happen:

- The password on the other machine needs to be updated to match.

or

- The user needs to clear existing credentials stored in the Credential Manager (and/or in the properties of any mapped drive connections) for that other computer, and then reconnect to the share so they can supply the right credentials.